# Cannot use injected service

Tags: typescript, angular

Import simple service into login.component.ts:`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TestService} from '../login/TestService';

@Component({
    providers: [TestService],
    templateUrl: './app/login/loginTemplate.html'
})
export class loginComponent  {
    constructor(testService: TestService){}

    sendLoginRequest() {
        this.testService.writeLine();
    }
}
```

Here is TestService file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable ()
export class TestService {
    constructor () {}

    writeLine () {
         return console.log("works from service");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the actual question?

Answer (score 2):

For this short form `private` or `public` is required

```
constructor(private testService: TestService){}
```

without this access modifier you need to do

```
testService;TestService;
constructor(testService: TestService){
  this.testService = testService;
}
```